# libgdx : Spritebatch not rendering until resize

Tags: libgdx, resize, render, spritebatch

**Long story short**: my spritebatch doesn't render anything until I resize the window (even by 1 pixel).

**Long story**: I'm following the Brent Aureli's tutorial on how to create the game Flappy Bird: Every game state (title menu, playing screen, pause screen etc) is a `State`. The `States` are managed in the form of a `Stack<State>` by the `GameStateManager`. The `GameStateManager` calls the classic loop methods of the `State` situated at the top of the stack.

**My problem**: the first `State` (whichever) that I push in the empty Stack renders just fine. However, if I pop/push to another state, it doesn't render anymore (I get glClearColor screen). If I just push another state, doesn't render either until I click at the bottom corner of my game window and resize. Then everything renders again.

I downloaded libgdx and Android sdk approximatively 4 weeks ago. I'm really confused.

Here's the code:

```js
public class MyGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    public static final int V_WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int V_HEIGHT = 480;
    public static final String title = "MyGame";

    private GameStateManager gsm;
    private SpriteBatch sb;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        
        sb = new SpriteBatch();
        gsm = new GameStateManager();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,1,0,1);
        gsm.push(new FooState(gsm));


    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gsm.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        gsm.render(sb);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        gsm.resize(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }
}


public abstract class State {
    protected OrthographicCamera cam;
    protected GameStateManager gsm;
    protected Viewport viewport;

    protected State(GameStateManager gsm){
        this.gsm = gsm;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Arlesian.V_WIDTH/2, Arlesian.V_HEIGHT/2, cam);
        viewport.apply();
    
    
    }

    protected abstract void handleInput();
    public abstract void update(float dt);
    public abstract void render(SpriteBatch sb);
    public abstract void resize(int width, int height);
    public abstract void dispose();
}



public class GameStateManager {
    private Stack<State> states;
    
    public GameStateManager(){
        states = new Stack<State>();
    }
    
    public void push(State state){
        states.push(state);
    }
    
    public void pop(){
        states.pop();
    }
    
    public void set(State state){
        states.peek().dispose();
        states.pop();
        states.push(state);
    }

    
    public void update(float dt){
        states.peek().handleInput();
        states.peek().update(dt);
    }
    
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb){
        states.peek().render(sb);
    }
    
    public void resize(int width, int height){
        states.peek().resize(width, height);
    }
}


public class FooState extends State {
    public FooState(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.V_WIDTH/2, MyGame.V_HEIGHT/2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            gsm.set(new FooState2(gsm));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }
}


public class FooState2 extends State {

    private Texture foo;
    private StretchViewport viewport;

    public FooState2(GameStateManager gsm) {
        super(gsm);
        foo = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        cam.setToOrtho(false, MyGame.V_WIDTH/2, MyGame.V_HEIGHT/2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleInput() {

    }

    @Override
    public void update(float dt) {
        cam.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
        sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sb.begin();
        sb.draw(foo, 0, 0);
        sb.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        foo.dispose();
    }
}
```

So basically: `FooState` doesn't do anything except for pushing a `FooState2` into the `GameStateManager` as soon as I touch the screen.

**What happens**: I touch the screen and I go into the `FooState2` loop of handleInput, update, render (I'm positively sure of that thanks to some Syso's). But the badlogic logo doesn't render, instead I get a glClearColor screen. Then I click at the border of the application window and resize just a bit, and the badlogic logo renders again.

**Another test**: If I just begin by solely pushing a FooState2 into the GameStateManager, badlogic logo renders without me needing to resize the window.

Can you help me, please?
Thanks in advance!
Sorry for my English if mistakes were made.

Comment: When I test your example code the badlogic texture is rendered as soon as I click the screen. No need for resizing. I think you forgot to add the class `State` in the code, you posted. The problem might be in this class.

Comment: Hello,
First of all thank you for taking the time to help me.
I added the code of the State class. All it does is declaring a new OrthographicCamera and apply a viewport.
If I don't apply the viewport, then I have the same issue, but trying to resize to solve the issue just ends in an error.
I don't know what I should modify...

Thanks in advance

Comment: When removing the line `viewport.apply()` it seems to be working again, but when debuggin it, I can't find anything that has changed in the camera. It is also very strange, that resizing the window fixes it although all the `resize` methods (in the `State` subclasses) are empty, so nothing is changed in the viewport... This might be a bug in the `Viewport` class of libGDX, but I'm not sure on that. I can't seem to find the problem. Sorry :(

Comment: Well, thank you at least for reassuring me on the validity of the code. I was also confused by the fact that the resize methods are empty and yet fix the problem!
I also tried to search for lines of code in any resize() method. Of course, there isn't any in the interface ApplicationListener.  There isn't any in the abstract class ApplicationAdapter either. And then it's my MyGame class...
I don't know where to look for the resize() code. Maybe I can find my answer there if someone knows where the code is.

Anyway thanks a lot!